# Exchange on premise Share GAL, calendar, free/busy without federation

Tags: exchange-server

first post. 'Lurked' for years but now joined to ask and contribute.

We have 2 trusted forests with on premise 2010 and 2013 exchange.

One domain will eventually be consumed as part of a hybrid 0365 environment, but not quite yet.

Until that happens, we have a small number using consuming services via two devices on both networks.

Is there a simple way of sharing busy/free and GAL info without federating in the cloud?

Just temporarily to avoid a further migration step when the hybrid is deployed and the other domain consumed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, we are looking at MIM still as an overall enterprise solution. We've still got a complex 3 GAL sync to contend with so we'll see!